# Python and django, how to extract data from the queryset

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have a question for you. I have the following class:

```
class StatoPatrimoniale(models.Model):
    reference_date=models.DateField()
    income=models.DecimalField()
    debt=models.DecimalField()
```

After that I have named a new variable `last_account_year` in th following manner:

```
now=datetime.datetime.now()
last_account_year=float(now.year)-1
```

Now I want to create a function that give me the possibility to extract the `income`and `debt` objects filtering them using the `last_account_year` and the year in the `reference_date`. 
How could I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the model [date field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#year):

```
StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=last_account_year)
```

And in a function encapsulating the logic and fixing it to zero if it doesn't exists:

```
def func(year):
    queryset = StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=year)
    return queryset if queryset.exists() else 0
```

Comment: Okey thanks, and if I want to fix it equal to zero if does not exsist?

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco I've added and example on my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use .filter() to filter your query and values_list() to get values: here is an exemple:

```
StatoPatrimoniale.objects.filter(reference_date__year=last_account_year).values_list('income', 'debt')
```

Comment: Okey thanks, and if I want to fix it equal to zero if data does not exsist?